# Find root path, shell script

Tags: shell

```
ROOT=`pwd | sed 's%\(.*/myABC\)/.*%\1%'`
```

This is a shell command , I believe the purpose is to find root path of this project.
I am not so sure how this work.
Could anyone help explain it for me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are in the directory path

/home/youruser/myABC/some/other/deeper/dir
and you use these command the path will be truncated to only /home/youruser/myABC/.

sed - is a string editing tool

s% - substitute the string of pwd and use '%' as separator

\(.*/myABC\)/.* - capture a string which contains myABC and save this in the first parameter

\1 - print first parameter

best regards kenny

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent directory of the current directory, couldn't you just do:

```
ROOT=`dirname $PWD`
```